# Is it possible to index a private maven repository in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, artifactory

Using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2, it complains that I have an un-indexed repo

```
The following repositories used in your gradle projects were not indexed yet: 
http://xxxxx.artifactoryonline.com/xxxxx/repo
If you want to use dependency completion for these repositories artifacts,
Open Repositories List, select required repositories and press "Update" button
```

However, when I go to preferences > build/execution/deployment > build tools > maven > repositories, and hit the update button for that repo, it just remains in an error state and there's no message in the event log.

When I hit the "test" button for the url, IntelliJ says "service connection failed, no repositories found". Nowhere does it allow for specifying credentials, only a url, so I suspect a credential issue or that maybe IntelliJ refuses to index private repos that require authentication.

My question is: Does IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 allow you to index private maven repos? If so, how do you enter credentials?

Comment: credentials could be in settings.xml ?

Comment: I don't have a settings.xml or even a .m2. Should I create that? I guess I figured IntelliJ would pick it up the same way gradle does from the build.gradle.

Comment: Are you sure? is `M2_HOME` set? user dir .m2 ?

Comment: M2_HOME is not set, and there is no .m2 folder in my home folder. I've never run maven on this machine, only gradle.